# Subrepresentations of dihedral group $D_4$ using the representation provided?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, dihedral-groups

Does the dihedral group $D_4$ have any sub-representations using the representation provided? if so, please can I have an example?

so we have:

$$D_4 = \lbrace e, r, r^2, r^3, c, d, x, y\rbrace$$

where $r$ is the rotation about the origin through $\pi/2$ (sending A to B).

while $c, d, x, y$ are  reflections in $AC,BD, O_x$ and $O_y$

we have the map

$$A(g):\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$$

the map $$g \mapsto A(g) \in GL(2,\mathbb{R})$$

defines a 2-dimensional representation $\rho$ over $\mathbb{R}$

the representation $\rho$ is given in matrix terms by

$e \mapsto 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0\\
0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
$, 
$r \mapsto 
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & -1\\
1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$,
$r^2 \mapsto 
\begin{bmatrix} 
-1 & 0\\
0 &-1\end{bmatrix}$,
$r^3 \mapsto 
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$,

$c \mapsto 
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1\\
1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$,
$d \mapsto 
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & -1\\
-1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$,
$x \mapsto 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0\\
0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$,
$y \mapsto 
\begin{bmatrix} 
-1 & 0\\
0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Can someone construct a subrepresentation using this example?

Comment: Please rephrase your post and be precise: a group does not have subrepresentation. A given representation does...and over which field are you working ? As far as I guess,  You are looking at real representations and you ask if your representation $\rho$ has subrepresentation, and i suppose that you are interested in NON TRIVIAL subrepresentations. But readers of your post shouldn't have to play guess....If I'm right, you are looking for a real line which is globally fixed by any of the eight matrices above. This does not exist since non trivial rotations do not fix any line.

Comment: @GreginGre so I'm interested in whether my $\rho$ has any sub-representations?

Comment: I don't know. You're the one asking this question :-) but if it is the case, there is no nontrivial subrepresentations, as I already said.

Comment: @GreginGre thank you for your insight! I'm sorry my questioning was a bit off